# No content to map to Object due to end of input (java.io.EOFException) Mule ESB CE

Tags: java, mule, esb

this is my project: [image]

1 getting json. 
 2 transforming json to object. 
 3 and 4 stock variable.
 5 java component for creating json to post (replace the datamapper). 
 7 post json to a web service. 
 9 get email from database and stock it into a session variable then building response.
And for the second flow i try to get the response of a web service wich in json format, {"success" = "1"} means that the web service has successfully sent a push. if not, an email must be send.
I tested each party of my code, but for sending json to a web service and getting response, i don't know what is the probleme.
when i run my code i get this error:

```
>     > ERROR 2015-04-07 00:07:49,654 [[ws3].flows1Flow2.stage1.02]
>     > org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>     > ******************************************************************************** Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to
>     > "java.lang.Object" Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
>     > -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>     > 1. No content to map to Object due to end of input (java.io.EOFException)   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper:2775
>     > (null)
>     > 2. Failed to transform from "json" to "java.lang.Object" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)  
>     > org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject:132
>     > (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
>     > -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to
>     > Object due to end of input  at
>     > org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
>     >     at
>     > org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
>     >     at
>     > org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1886)
>     >     + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>     > ********************************************************************************
```

** The error was fixed it was because we have to send parameters to this web service not json for this i tried:

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost"
        port="3306" user="root" database="mulesoft" doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail"
        validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail" />
    <flow name="Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"
            contentType="application/json" path="getDetails" />
        <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="tkn"
            value="#[message.payload.token]" doc:name="token" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="msg"
            value="#[message.payload.msg]" doc:name="message" />
        <component class="ws1.Transformer" doc:name="Java">

            <method-entry-point-resolver>
                <include-entry-point method="methhod" />
            </method-entry-point-resolver>

        </component>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
        <logger message="&quot;I can get properties this is app&quot;+#[message.payload.application]+&quot;this is the type&quot;+#[message.payload.type]"
            level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />


        <set-property propertyName="application"
            value="#[message.payload.application]" doc:name="Property" />
        <set-property propertyName="token" value="#[sessionVars['tkn']]"
            doc:name="Property" />
        <set-property propertyName="user" value="#[message.payload.user]"
            doc:name="Property" />

        <set-property propertyName="type" value="#[message.payload.type]"
            doc:name="Property" />

        <set-property propertyName="message" value="#[sessionVars['msg']]"
            doc:name="Property" />

        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            method="POST" address="http://slice.WS.com/api.php/push/send_test_push" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from push where token = #[sessionVars['tkn']]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <set-session-variable variableName="email"
                value="#[message.payload.email]" doc:name="Session Variable" />
        </foreach>
        <response>
            <http:response-builder status="200" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
        </response>
    </flow>

 <flow name="wsFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://slice.WS.com/api.php/push/send_test_push" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </poll>
        <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]+ &quot;payload&quot;"
            level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <!--   json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/> -->
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="true">
                <logger message="its ok" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-payload value="Dear Mail Crawler,
                    \n\n No spam to my email, please!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" user="myemail%40gmail.com" password="pass" connector-ref="Gmail" to="#[message.payload.email]" from="Rajeun" subject="Mule Test with Velocity Transformer" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
```

when i test by sending json via postman i get this:

```
    INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:47,346 [[ws3].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: "I can get properties this is app"+91+"this is the type"+Android
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:47,384 [[ws3].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:47,391 [[ws3].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:47,391 [[ws3].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:47,392 [[ws3].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.1593171'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:47,395 [[ws3].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.1593171'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,122 [pool-19-thread-1] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,122 [pool-19-thread-1] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,122 [pool-19-thread-1] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,137 [pool-19-thread-1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.31829235'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,137 [pool-19-thread-1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.31829235'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,642 [[ws3].wsFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: + "payload"
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:48,647 [[ws3].wsFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: its ok
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:49,691 [[ws3].wsFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: + "payload"
INFO  2015-04-07 16:09:49,692 [[ws3].wsFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: its ok
```

that's mean that parameters didn't arrive to the web service.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `foreach`: it seems you're iterating to overwrite the same session variable (`"email"`) several times if there are several rows. Why not just setting the session variable with the value from the last row instead?

Comment: The error happens in the flow named `flows1Flow2`: can you please fully post its XML?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I was in the process of testing the first part of my code. I removed the foreach it gave an error, and there is all the code http://pastebin.com/jBY2Rcwc

Comment: also for testing i created this flow http://pastebin.com/fHFVzNEY and the result means that i don't receive any response from the web service. So the json posted (in the first flow) for sending a push didn't arrive.

Comment: {"success" = "1"} is not really JSON. Is that what you're getting or did you mean {"success": "1"}?

Comment: When i test the web service with postman i get this: {"success":0,"failed":1}

Comment: even if I am not receiving json. In the second test that  I did here http://pastebin.com/fHFVzNEY I try to see what I get but apparently I receive nothing from the web service ...

Comment: I'm not sure if that web service is something you can only use locally yourself but I get a 500 error and no body. Could there be some headers missing?

Comment: thank you @afelisatti , your question was useful to me. now i need to send  to the web service parameters and not in json format. Now the question is how to do that with the json that i have in my payload.

Comment: You need to extract the JSON data from the payload and use it to set the necessary HTTP data (headers and such). I believe you can set the return class of the JSON transformer to HashMap for easy access to the data.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. thank you in advance.